# Multiple Item price depends on remaining quantities

Tags: ms-access-2016

When I'm entering the **order** Invoice I want to bring the buying price of (Item1) and its Remaining quantities from (purchaseDetail) table,

(Item1) had multiple records in the (purchaseDetail) table depends on it's **purchase** invoice .

In my continuous subform **ordersDetailSubform** I have a combobox **cboItemsName**  .

So , depends on the quantity I entered and the previous quantity of Item1 **orders** I want to bring the buying price list as a **row source**  query of **cboItemsName** containing only the available quantity prices .

| ItemId | quantity | buyPrice |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 3$ |
| 1 | 10 | 2$ |

Let's say I have previous orders of Item1 of quantity (4) .

If I now entering my new order In my orders form , when I'm typing (Item1)  , the **cboItemsName** row source query show me the Remaining quantities and its prices like that

| remaining quantities | buying Price |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 $ |
| 10 | 2 $ |

Can help with the best Ideas to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the remaining quantity of each item and it's bought price appears in the combo box that you have in your ordersDetailSubform but the price that you want to be shown should be the last price of the item that you purchased the item.
For every item one price can come with the remaining quantity in the combo box list.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).